# How to send yii2 custom form field response to email

Tags: php, yii2

I have created an additional field to collect website address in the default basic Yii2 template. I have been trying to get the response to be sent via email along with other responses.

The code below I belief controls this function:

```
public function contact($email)
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
            ->setTo($email)
            ->setFrom([$this->email => $this->name])
            ->setSubject('Message from Website Contact Form')
            ->setTextBody($this->website)
            ->setTextBody($this->details)               
            ->send();

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I added `->setTextBody($this->website)` but it did not show the website in the email. I don't know if `->setTextBody` is the right code to use.
This is what is delivered below:

Message-ID: <5de1ed1ddd9b60dd923c60296f14b5ee@localhost>
Date: Sat, 23 Mar 2019 15:47:22 +0100
Subject: Message from Website Contact Form
From: Niyi 
To: admin@example.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

asmbdnvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbb=
bbbbbbbbbb

Any idea on how ti resolve this. I am thinking using `->setTextBody($this->website => $this->details)` will work but even if it does, I want them separated on different line/paragraph

Answer (score 2):

Notice that you are calling `setTextBody` twice, and that doesn't make sense.
The value that has been set by the first call gets overwritten by the second call.
So what you see in the message is the contents of `$this->details` only, it's no surprise that you don't see the contents of `$this->website`.

Setting text body like this `setTextBody($this->website => $this->details)` also won't work. In the first place, because it's a wrong php syntax. And even if you fix it like this `setTextBody([$this->website => $this->details])`, it will also fail, because `setTextBody` expects only plain text as input.

If you want `$this->website` and `$this->details` to be both included and be on separate lines, try doing like this: `setTextBody("$this->website\r\n\r\n$this->details")`